# ASP.NET hosting - limited number of database accounts

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, hosting, shared-hosting, iis-7.5

My ASP.NET host only allows 3 database users per db other than the dbo.

I have one for the web app that only runs stored procs and has limited selects to tables.

One for ASP.NET membership/roles.

One for SQL cache dependency/notification.

One for logging - ELMAH / log4net.

How would you consolidate the 4 users into 3?  How do you get around limited database user accounts in ASP.NET hosts?

I'm thinking of combining the web app and logging accounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that combining the logging and web application databases would be the most sensible choice - if you want to try and keep the separation then you could prefix the table names.